# Use multiple public directories in Sinatra

Tags: sinatra, assets, public

My sinatra application is contained in a gem. This means that the assets (css/js) live in the gem. This application writes on the fly generated images and serves them; currently writing into and serving from the public dir.

I prefer to not write the generated images in the gem dir but to a "cache" dir of some sorts under the web-application implementing this gem.

Gem is installed at `/var/www/TE/shared/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/tubemp-0.6.0`, so assets are at e.g. `/var/www/TE/shared/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/tubemp-0.6.0/lib/public/css/`.

Gem is deployed in a simple rack-app at `/var/www/TE/current/`, so I would prefer to write and serve the thumbnails from `/var/www/TE/current/public`.

However, the setting for a custom public-dir allows only one dir to be set:

```
set :public_folder, File.join(Dir.pwd, "public")
```

Breaks the serving of assets; Dir.pwd being the directory of the Rack app. Public is now the dir under the Rack-app, but that is not where the assets are found: they live under the "public" in the gem.

```
set :public_folder, File.join(gemdir, "public")
```

Breaks serving of the generated thumbnails.

I could rewrite the application so it serves either the assets or the thumbnails trough Sinatra, but that seems quite some overhead.

Is that the only way? Or is there a way to give Sinatra two or more public dirs to [serve its static items](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/1.3.x/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L918) from?

Comment: Forgive me if I'm not entirely clear on what's happening. What's stopping you from writing the generated images into the rack app's public dir?

Comment: Nothing; but that requires me setting that dir as "public" and then suddenly the assets shipped with the gem (..../1.8/gems/foo-0.0.0/public/javascript/application.js) is no longer served. Updated the Q to explain this.

Comment: That's a lot clearer, thanks. I've added an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's probably a few options, but here's how I got a little app to serve static files from two places, an extension and the main app's public folder:

#### Directory layout

```
root/
  app.rb
  public/images/foo.jpg
  lib/sinatra/
       gemapp.rb
       gemapp/public/images/bar.jpg
```

#### The extension

```
# lib/sinatra/gemapp.rb
module Sinatra
  module GemApp
    def self.registered(app)

      app.set :gem_images, File.expand_path( "gemapp/public/images", File.dirname(__FILE__))

      app.get "/images/:file" do |file|
        send_file File.join( settings.gem_images, file)
      end

      app.get "/gemapp" do
        "running"
      end
    end
  end
  register GemApp
end
```

#### The main app

```
require 'sinatra'

require_relative "./lib/sinatra/gemapp.rb"

get "/" do
  "home"
end
```

It served files fine for me.

Comment: I feared that serving assets trough a Sinatra route would be the only option. A pity, but I can soften the pain a little by tweaking nginx to serve the assets from its cache.

Comment: @berkes why is that a bad thing?

Comment: serving static assets is AFAIK a lot faster when not served trough the sinatra.

Comment: @berkes If doing it this way then I'd use the route to add caching headers and possibly a unique URL for the image, with a helper to help find it. That way the pain is only the first hit but you get some benefits you wouldn't via just Nginx. Otherwise, yes, Nginx would be a lot quicker, but then I'd just get the app to write to a directory Nginx was serving from and skip Rack altogether.

Comment: @berkes Something like this trick http://openmonkey.com/2009/02/09/caching-and-expring-stylesheets-and-javascripts-in-sinatra/ Perhaps it won't be applicable in your case.

Comment: I think code is not secure. What happens if someone types in "../.env" for the filename? They will have access to the app's secrets. Constructing a path from user input is not safe. There needs to an enforced root dir for the static assets.

Comment: @maxpleaner I agree. Copy and pasting example code from the internet without consideration can lead to bad results. This code is here as a simple example and should not be used in production as is!